# Java Help with Logic in XML SAX Handler

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax, handler

I am trying to set up a SAX Handler to parse XML with the following structure:

```
<Hours>
  <Set name="BUSINESS">
        <MO>
              <Open>09:00:00</Open>
              <Close>17:00:00</Close>
        </MO>
        <TU>
              <Open>09:00:00</Open>
              <Close>17:00:00</Close>
        </TU>
        <WE>
              <Open>09:00:00</Open>
              <Close>17:00:00</Close>
        </WE>
        <TH>
              <Open>09:00:00</Open>
              <Close>17:00:00</Close>
        </TH>
        <FR>
              <Open>09:00:00</Open>
              <Close>17:00:00</Close>
        </FR>
        <SA/>
        <SU/>
  </Set>
  <Set name="LASTCOLLECTION">
        <MO>
              <Close>17:00:00</Close>
        </MO>
        <TU>
              <Close>17:00:00</Close>
        </TU>
        <WE>
              <Close>17:00:00</Close>
        </WE>
        <TH>
              <Close>17:00:00</Close>
        </TH>
        <FR>
              <Close>17:00:00</Close>
        </FR>
        <SA/>
        <SU/>
  </Set>
 </Hours>
```

I am running into some problems, however. My code will only really get the value of OPEN and CLOSE in MO, not in any of the other days of the week. Can anyone find a flaw in my logic? Here is my handler code:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Set")
            && attributes.getValue("name").equalsIgnoreCase(
                    "BUSINESS")) {
        inBusiness = true;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Set")
            && attributes.getValue("name").equalsIgnoreCase(
                    "LASTCOLLECTION")) {
        inLastCollection = true;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("MO")) {
        inMonday = true;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("TU")) {
        inTuesday = true;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("WE")) {
        inWednesday = true;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("TH")) {
        inThursday = true;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("FR")) {
        inFriday = true;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("SA")) {
        inSaturday = true;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("SU")) {
        inSunday = true;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Open")) {
        inOpen = true;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Close")) {
        inClose = true;
    }

}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {

    value = value + new String(ch, start, length).trim();

}

public void endElement(String uri, String name, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

    if (inBusiness) {

        bHours = new BusinessHours();

        if (inMonday) {

            if (inOpen) {
                bHours.setMondayOpen(value);
                inOpen = false;
            } else if (inClose) {
                bHours.setMondayClose(value);
                inClose = false;
            }
            inMonday = false;

        } else if (inTuesday) {
            if (inOpen) {
                bHours.setTuesdayOpen(value);
                inOpen = false;
            } else if (inClose) {
                bHours.setTuesdayClose(value);
                inClose = false;
            }
            inTuesday = false;
        } else if (inWednesday) {
            if (inOpen) {
                bHours.setWednesdayOpen(value);
                inOpen = false;
            } else if (inClose) {
                bHours.setWednesdayClose(value);
                inClose = false;
            }
            inWednesday = false;
        } else if (inThursday) {
            if (inOpen) {
                bHours.setThursdayOpen(value);
                inOpen = false;
            } else if (inClose) {
                bHours.setThursdayClose(value);
                inClose = false;
            }
            inThursday = false;
        } else if (inFriday) {
            if (inOpen) {
                bHours.setFridayOpen(value);
                inOpen = false;
            } else if (inClose) {
                bHours.setFridayClose(value);
                inClose = false;
            }
            inFriday = false;
        } else if (inSaturday) {
            if (inOpen) {
                bHours.setSaturdayOpen(value);
                inOpen = false;
            } else if (inClose) {
                bHours.setSaturdayClose(value);
                inClose = false;
            }
            inSaturday = false;
        } else if (inSunday) {
            if (inOpen) {
                bHours.setSundayOpen(value);
                inOpen = false;
            } else if (inClose) {
                bHours.setSundayClose(value);
                inClose = false;
            }
            inSunday = false;

        }
        myLoc.setBusinessHours(bHours);
        inBusiness = false;
    } else if (inLastCollection) {

        cHours = new LastCollectionHours();

        if (inMonday) {

            if (inOpen) {
                cHours.setMondayOpen(value);
                inOpen = false;
            } else if (inClose) {
                cHours.setMondayClose(value);
                inClose = false;
            }
            inMonday = false;

        } else if (inTuesday) {
            if (inOpen) {
                cHours.setTuesdayOpen(value);
                inOpen = false;
            } else if (inClose) {
                cHours.setTuesdayClose(value);
                inClose = false;
            }
            inTuesday = false;
        } else if (inWednesday) {
            if (inOpen) {
                cHours.setWednesdayOpen(value);
                inOpen = false;
            } else if (inClose) {
                cHours.setWednesdayClose(value);
                inClose = false;
            }
            inWednesday = false;
        } else if (inThursday) {
            if (inOpen) {
                cHours.setThursdayOpen(value);
                inOpen = false;
            } else if (inClose) {
                cHours.setThursdayClose(value);
                inClose = false;
            }
            inThursday = false;
        } else if (inFriday) {
            if (inOpen) {
                cHours.setFridayOpen(value);
                inOpen = false;
            } else if (inClose) {
                cHours.setFridayClose(value);
                inClose = false;
            }
            inFriday = false;
        } else if (inSaturday) {
            if (inOpen) {
                cHours.setSaturdayOpen(value);
                inOpen = false;
            } else if (inClose) {
                cHours.setSaturdayClose(value);
                inClose = false;
            }
            inSaturday = false;
        } else if (inSunday) {
            if (inOpen) {
                cHours.setSundayOpen(value);
                inOpen = false;
            } else if (inClose) {
                cHours.setSundayClose(value);
                inClose = false;
            }
            inSunday = false;

        }
        myLoc.setLastCollectionHours(cHours);
        inLastCollection = false;
    }

}
```

---

UPDATED CODE:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    value = new String();

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Set")
            && attributes.getValue("name").equalsIgnoreCase("BUSINESS")) {
        currentElement = 1;
        bHours = new BusinessHours();

    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Set")
            && attributes.getValue("name").equalsIgnoreCase(
                    "LASTCOLLECTION")) {
        currentElement = 2;
        cHours = new LastCollectionHours();
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("MO")) {
        day = 1;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("TU")) {
        day = 2;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("WE")) {
        day = 3;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("TH")) {
        day = 4;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("FR")) {
        day = 5;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("SA")) {
        day = 6;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("SU")) {
        day = 7;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Open")) {
        open = 1;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Close")) {
        open = 2;
    }

}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {

    value = value + new String(ch, start, length).trim();

} // end Method Characters

public void endElement(String uri, String name, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Set") && currentElement == 1) {
        myLoc.setBusinessHours(bHours);
    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Set") && currentElement == 2) {
        myLoc.setLastCollectionHours(cHours);

    }

    if (currentElement == 1) {

        if (day == 1) {

            if (open == 1) {
                bHours.setMondayOpen(value);
            } else if (open == 2) {
                bHours.setMondayClose(value);
            }

        } else if (day == 2) {

            if (open == 1) {
                bHours.setTuesdayOpen(value);
            } else if (open == 2) {
                bHours.setTuesdayClose(value);
            }
        } else if (day == 3) {

            if (open == 1) {
                bHours.setWednesdayOpen(value);
            } else if (open == 2) {
                bHours.setWednesdayClose(value);
            }
        } else if (day == 4) {

            if (open == 1) {
                bHours.setThursdayOpen(value);
            } else if (open == 2) {
                bHours.setThursdayClose(value);
            }
        } else if (day == 5) {

            if (open == 1) {
                bHours.setFridayOpen(value);
            } else if (open == 2) {
                bHours.setFridayClose(value);
            }
        } else if (day == 6) {

            if (open == 1) {
                bHours.setSaturdayOpen(value);
            } else if (open == 2) {
                bHours.setSaturdayClose(value);
            }
        } else if (day == 7) {

            if (open == 1) {
                bHours.setSundayOpen(value);
            } else if (open == 2) {
                bHours.setSundayClose(value);
            }

        }

    } else if (currentElement == 2) {

        if (day == 1) {

            if (open == 1) {
                cHours.setMondayOpen(value);
            } else if (open == 2) {
                cHours.setMondayClose(value);
            }

        } else if (day == 2) {

            if (open == 1) {
                cHours.setTuesdayOpen(value);
            } else if (open == 2) {
                cHours.setTuesdayClose(value);
            }
        } else if (day == 3) {

            if (open == 1) {
                cHours.setWednesdayOpen(value);
            } else if (open == 2) {
                cHours.setWednesdayClose(value);
            }
        } else if (day == 4) {

            if (open == 1) {
                cHours.setThursdayOpen(value);
            } else if (open == 2) {
                cHours.setThursdayClose(value);
            }
        } else if (day == 5) {

            if (open == 1) {
                cHours.setFridayOpen(value);
            } else if (open == 2) {
                cHours.setFridayClose(value);
            }
        } else if (day == 6) {

            if (open == 1) {
                cHours.setSaturdayOpen(value);
            } else if (open == 2) {
                cHours.setSaturdayClose(value);
            }
        } else if (day == 7) {

            if (open == 1) {
                cHours.setSundayOpen(value);
            } else if (open == 2) {
                cHours.setSundayClose(value);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Line 116 You are setting inBusiness = false - which will get set after **monday's** open/close. Next time around it fails the if(inBusiness) on line 44.

Instead of using a inBusiness boolean, use a int indicator as follows:

private int curElement = 0;

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

```
if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Set")
        && attributes.getValue("name").equalsIgnoreCase(
                "BUSINESS")) {
    curElement = 1;
} else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Set")
        && attributes.getValue("name").equalsIgnoreCase(
                "LASTCOLLECTION")) {
    curElement = 2;
}
```

......

}

public void endElement(String uri, String name, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

```
if (curElement == 1) {

    ....
    //Remove inBusiness= false;
} else if (curElement == 2) {
    ...
    //Remove inLastCollection = false;
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand - then how else am I supposed to differentiate between when I am inside of BUSINESS and when I am inside of LASTCOLLECTION? The only place that I am setting inBusiness = false is after all of the if statements dealing with the weekdays..

Comment: inBusiness = false was being executed on any day, not only in the if(isSunday)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I see what you mean now. I changed the code to use an int, however now I am receiving null values for all of the hours once I check the vector afterwards...

Comment: The output has the following pattern (with my println statements) IN BUSINESS, IN MONDAY, IN BUSINESS, IN BUSINESS, IN BUSINESS, IN BUSINESS, IN BUSINESS, IN TUESDAY, IN BUSINESS, IN BUSINESS, IN BUSINESS, IN BUSINESS, IN BUSINESS, IN WEDNESDAY, etc.

Comment: could it be that you are setting bHours = new BusinessHours() for every day? what does myLoc.setBusinessHours do? can you please post the entire code?

Comment: Ah, yes, I believe that was part of it. The LastCollection (or currentValue = 2) stuff is now setting hours correctly. There are now more hours for BUSINESS filled in, however some of the OPEN and CLOSE are still null. What i did was I moved the bHours = new BusinessHours() up where I set currentValue = 1. myLoc.setBusinessHours just sets the BusinessHours object into a vector

Comment: Can you please post the updated code? which hours don't work? are you aware that the LASTCOLLECTION set have only close hours? and finally, where do you clear the value variable, which is only appended to in the characters method on line 39: value = value + new String(ch, start, length).trim();

Comment: I have posted the updated code. I am aware that LASTCOLLECTION only has close hours, that's how it is supposed to be. If you look at the top of startElement(), that is where I will set value = new String(); Some of the close hours don't work in BUSINESS and some of the open hours don't work in BUSINESS..

Comment: I also tried setting myLoc.setBusinessHours(bHours) when a "SET" tag is encountered in endElement(), but I received the same results. The only time that I want to set bHours to myLoc is when the parser has gone through BUSINESS from start to finish...

Comment: in the updated code, you did not remove the bHours = new BusinessHours() in the endElement method

Comment: What does the BusinessHours.setMondayOpen method do exactly?... what is happening is that on the one hand you have different methods for setMondayClose and setTuesdayClose etc, but on the other hand you are creating a NEW instance of BusinessHours for every day. that might be your issue

Comment: That just sets a private string from within the BusinessHours class. This way, after all of the parsing is done, I can have access that string from within a vector of MyLocationClass objects

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on how I can change my logic?

Comment: inMonday = false is happening after the OPEN, so when it gets to the close, inMonday is now false.

Comment: use the same approach as inBusiness, use a int indicator instead of a bunch of booleans

Comment: i would also change the logic to either use 1 instance of the BusinessHours class instead of 7

Comment: Thanks for all of your help on this. I have changed my code to use ints rather than booleans to detect the days of the week as well as open vs close. It looks like everything is working now except the Monday close hours are wrong. They appear as the opening hours rather than the close hours. Other than that, everything looks good...

Comment: Also, The Saturday open hours for BUSINESS are also getting null values (and they are supposed to blank). The Sunday BUSINESS hours are appearing as blank.  Both the Saturday and the Sunday hours appear as blank for LASTCOLLECTION

Comment: is the problem in the business set or the lastcollection set

Comment: I do not have any java editer installed, so i cannot step through the code in a debugger, but i think The problem is that when the </monday> tag closes, the currentElement is still 1, day is still 1 and the open is till 2, however the value is empty becouse when the <set> element started the value = String()

Comment: the sat & sun tags dont have <open> and <close> tags, thats why they are null

Comment: Well the value of CLOSE for Monday (for BUSINESS) is not empty or null, it is 9:00:00 instead of 17:00:00. Do you have any recommendations on fixing what you said above?

Comment: Nevermind, everything is working now. Seeing as how I have been looking at this for hours, I didn't notice that my print statement was printing the OPEN instead of CLOSE. Thanks for all of your help!